# Why is nextjs trying to import a stylesheet which doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Recently, I noticed that Nextjs is trying to import a stylesheet that doesn't exist (pictures below).
I'm wondering how to fix this error.

Hopefully I can find a solution here,
cheers

[Webbrowser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOuMa.png)
[Webbrowser network headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ec2P.png)

[Initiator data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkldW.png)

Comment: In the Network Panel you can see the initiator (how requested that resource).  What does it say?

Comment: @oliverwebr I added the picture to the question

Comment: Can you show us your `/login` page's code?

Comment: It is for every page and what exactly you want to see?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to import the fonts via `<link/>` and not over `@import` style cs